# Should axes $Ox_i$ or coordinates of a point $x_i$ be used in notation for gradient?

Tags: calculus

In Nye p.5 I read:

> We sometimes use the symbols $x_1,x_2,x_3$ instead of $Ox_1,Ox_2,Ox_3$
> to denote the direction of the axes when no confusion can arise with
> the coordinates of a point, which are also denoted by $x_1,x_2,x_3$.

This has me wondering, Should axes $Ox_i$ or coordinates of a point $x_i$ be used in notation for gradient? E.g., for scalar $f$, do we write the gradient as,
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial Ox_i}$$
or as,
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$$?